# Change tile color on tap

Tags: android, tiles, libgdx

Alright, so let's say I have a tile map that looks like this:

[image]

When the user touches the blue part on the right (I handle the coordinates and all that) how can I make the blue part turn into a different color (a different set of tiles, let's say green tiles I have created some green tiles)?

Comment: Can you add some code to how you are loading/drawing your tiles? Are you using TileRenderer? Are you using SpriteCache to draw?

Comment: The same code as here: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/TiledMapTest.java

Answer (score 0):

Since the TileRenderer is using a SpriteCache internally, you can't change the texture used to render a particular tile after its loaded. However, you can use multiple layers in your map and conditionally have an extra layer with green tiles render on top of your red/blue tiles using [render(camera,layer[])](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/tiled/TileMapRenderer.html#render%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera,%20int%5B%5D%29). If the green tiles do not cover up the blue tiles completely, then you will have to have separate layers for blue,green,and red tiles, and have green or blue tiles render on top of red tile conditionally. Keep in mind that tile maps are not meant for larges scale animations and is more suited for static terrain.

Answer (score -1):

[EDIT] right answer below in the comments

```
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer orthogonalTiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1/tileSize);

orthogonalTiledMapRenderer.getSpriteBatch().setColor(/*wished color*/);
```

Comment: Could you please properly format your answer and add a qualitative explanation?

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why this works.  Code dumping without explanation is usually not encouraged here.

Comment: I wanted to post this somewhere else. The best solution i can come up with here is to change individual tiles at a certain position. I use this myself in my game to change the look of a tile while the player is standing on it. The tile and it's body are being removed after some time. TiledMapTileLayer tiledMapTileLayer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get("background");   and then when you need it you change the texture of the tile at position x,y:tiledMapTileLayer.getCell(x, y) .setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(TextureRegion textureRegion));